# jQueryUI sortable strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

My friend made a HTML, I just added jQueryUI and made a part sortable. But it's responding awkwardly. Can you guys have a look and suggest what to do to fix is?

This is the JSBin.

http://jsbin.com/woyami/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: can you describe "awkwardly" so we know what we're looking at?

Comment: Please, go to the JS Bin, and try to drag an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.

> remove **float:left** from ***"#designSidebar"***
>
> and
>
> remove **display: inline; float: left;** from
>   ***".designtheme_area"***

It will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what you are looking for but I'd go for that:

```
    $("#main-navigation").sortable({
          opacity: 0.6, 
          cursor: 'move', 
          tolerance: 'pointer'});
```

Comment: But after doing so, when dragging an element to sort, the page automatically scrolls down. So we can not sort the elements.

Comment: It is not for me, in both cases.

Comment: Can you look at the jsbin link I've gave?

Comment: I did and it acts normal. It is not scrolling for me if that is your problem.

Comment: I got it, it's a CSS issue. It's only acting strange on Chrome on a Mac.